# Getting specific column names inside a function with tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to write a function to obtain some lab values across various dataframes. However, I have trouble when I try to summarize the lab values by taking the mean with `summarise()`. I've tried to run `deparse(substitute(y))` but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know how to identify my y variable in a way that tidyverse recognizes.

```
obtain_labvalues <- function(df,y){
  baseline <- df %>% group_by(serial_no) %>%
    filter(ref_date %within% interval(diagnosis- months(6),diagnosis)) %>%
    filter(ref_date == max(ref_date)) %>%
    summarize(across(!!y, mean)) %>%
    arrange(serial_no)}
```

I tried running this code for a df called bmi and the variable I wanted to take the mean of was bmi: `mean_df <- obtain_labvalues(bmi,bmi)` but it still doesn't work, where did I get it wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Try with `summarise(across(!!y, mean)) %>%`. For older version `dplyr`, use `summarise_at(vars(!!y), mean)`

Comment: ```
 Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..1`.
x Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `data.frame<
  serial_no: character
  ref_date : date
  bmi      : double
>`.
i It must be numeric or character.
i Input `..1` is `across(...)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: serial_no = "03300572".
```
I ran with ```summarize(across(!!y, mean)) %>% ```  but it produced this error, sorry I'm a beginner with R but what does that mean?

Comment: How did you call that function? Perhaps update the question and share some code snippets? It's very hard to debug without knowing the code.

Comment: Updated with the codes I used thanks!

Comment: Try `obtain_labvalues(bmi,"bmi")`

Comment: Thanks a lot it works!! Just like to learn more though, what does the !! in ```summarize(across(!!y, mean))``` actually do?

Comment: Tell `across` to not use the symbol y but evaluate y and use its value (i.e. "bmi"). See [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/07/bang-bang-how-to-program-with-dplyr/) for more details.